# Print icon placement on a webpage

Tags: usability, buttons, layout

I am producing a site that generates financial information based on user inputs.

Users input their expected financial contributions and are provided with a visual representation, graph and table of their future potential returns.

It would be beneficial for the user to be able to print this information for their own records.

My question is should the print button be at the top of the screen where users can quickly print the information to read it later or at the end of the information so that it is the final step in their user journey?

The button would be visible when the user enters the page regardless of it's position.

Personally I think it should go at the top of the page but I have no evidence to back up this decision.

Comment: Welcome to UX.SE
It would be great if you can share a wireframe structure to better understand. Is there any action button on page, which needs to be pressed afgter user provides details? Like, Generate the report, etc. 
Is it a form?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot upload images (network security).  There are no action buttons result are calculated following a change on any of the inputs

Comment: In the browser chrome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Print icons go in the top right of your screen. [In eye tracking terms, this is a strong fallow area](http://www.vanseodesign.com/web-design/3-design-layouts/), and makes a good place for secondary actions like printing.

This is a scenario where there is a strong conventional design pattern, and you probably shouldn't mess around with it.

If printing is the primary action i.e. users most often get to the end of page and need/want to print, you could add a Call To Action button at the end of page in addition to the conventional icon/text in the top right.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your page design.

> The best position would be the point where user provides the last mandatory detail. That is the area where the print or call to action button must be placed.

And hence it depends on the design or depth of the page. If its above the fold, you can provide immediately after the last input that is suppose to be filled by the user.

[image]

If the form is lengthy, and deep, where the user needs to scroll to finish the form filling , its good practice to keep a print icon at both the places, top and bottom where the form ends. 
[image]